# "Explore" button not available

Tags: experience-editor, geo-location

In Experience Editor, the "Explore" button is not enabled. The license has permissions to analytics, and GeoIP was purchased and turned on. I was going to use the "Explore" button to access the test link for the GeoIP, but it's not enabled on the bar. It does work on our QA server, however. I'm marked as an administrator, so I'd think I'd have access.

Comment: can you  verify if this setting is true ? Xdb.Tracking.Enabled

Comment: It's set to false, but I thought it was supposed to be set false on CM so you aren't tracking on the CM. https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/experience_management/configuring/disabling_xdb_and_the_xdb_tracker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had Xdb.Tracking.Enabled set to "false" on my CM, which I thought was necessary to keep the CM from doing tracking...Sitecore even seems to suggest doing this: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/experience_management/configuring/disabling_xdb_and_the_xdb_tracker. Then I saw the note about changing the setting would knock out personalization and GeoIP. I changed it back, the Explore button came back, and I could hit the GeoIP test link again.